# How to solve this `unorderable types` error

Tags: python, if-statement

I keep getting the following error and my program will not run. I need to make sure my program is modular and have the `if-then` statements to figure out what gross pay equation to use.

```
BASE_HOURS = 40
OT_MULTIPLIER = 1.5

def main():
    hours = input("Enter the number of hours worked: ")
    payRate = input("Enter the hourly pay rate: ")
    calcPayWithOT(hours,payRate)

def calcPayWithOT(hours,payRate):
    if hours <= BASE_HOURS:
        theGrossPayNoOT = hours * payRate
        print("The gross pay is $ ", theGrossPayNoOT)
    if hours > BASE_HOURS:
        theGrossPayOT = (hours - BASE_HOURS) * OT_MULTIPLIER + (hours * payRate)
        print("The gross pay is $ ", theGrossPayOT)
main()
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the specific error message.

Comment: Added image of the error message I get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the `hours` and `payRate` into integers or floats like so:

```
hours = int(input("Enter the number of hours worked: "))
payRate = int(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))
```

or

```
hours = float(input("Enter the number of hours worked: "))
payRate = float(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))
```

Depending if you want to include only natural numbers or ones with figures after the decimal `.`

Comment: You type faster than me !

Comment: Yes, this helped! it took care of my error. Now I have a new question I am not getting the correct output from my program. Do you see where I made a mistake? The values I'm entering is 100 hours and 10 for pay rate should output $1,300 but, I'm getting $1,090.

Comment: $1090 is correct as I see by your program. Are you sure this is your equation? `(hours - BASE_HOURS) * OT_MULTIPLIER + (hours * payRate)`

Comment: I've actually just corrected it but it still isn't giving me the correct answer. theGrossPayOT = (hours - BASE_HOURS) * (OT_MULTIPLIER * payRate) + (hours * payRate)

Comment: How did you calculate $1,300? Perhaps I can write the correct equation.

Comment: if hours are 100 and rate is 10. I need to take (100 - 40) * (10 * 1.5)[this should give me gross pay of just OT hours] + (40 * 10)[this gives me gross pay of reg hours]

Comment: `theGrossPayOT = (hours - BASE_HOURS) * OT_MULTIPLIER * payRate + (BASE_HOURS * payRate)`.

Comment: I totally overlooked that, Thank you!